# Applied Mathematics Book on Integro-Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

I'm interested in teaching a course on integro-differential equations and their applications. I was wondering if anyone could suggest a decent book on the subject. I'm currently looking at "Nonlocal Diffusion Problems" by Andreu-Vaillo, Mazón, Rossi, and Toledo-Melero. Is there a better book or would this be sufficient for a course? Any advice is greatly appreciated.